# VM mac adress is identical as the host device

Tags: arp, spoofing

I'm using Oracle VM Kali Linux.

I tried arp spoofing on home network, but other devices other than host receives router's mac as the host pcs mac adress instead of the VM machine's although on wireshark, the correct 'VM' mac adress is in the arp reply packet. Only the host pc sees the VM's mac.

The configuration of network settings is this:
[image]

What might be the problem here?